# Can't chmod SSH key for git through git bash on windows 8 embedded

Tags: git, windows-8, github, ssh

On Windows Embedded 8 Industry Pro, with git 1.9, I tried to generate SSH keys following https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys. The key is generated correctly, and I added it to my keys.

Then when I try to check the generated key with ssh -T git@github.com, I receive the message:

```
Permissions 0644 for 'pathtothekey' are too open.
```

The issue is that when I can't change permissions with chmod via git bash ! I also tried to change them via cygwin and cmd: the permissions are changed, but with ls -la via git bash, the permission is still 0644 for the key ! I also tried to regenerate the key and even to reinstall Git but without any success...

Has anyone had the same issue ? I use Git through batch scripts so this issue is really annoying...

Answer (score 0):

The key needs to be shown only to you, that's what the warning suggests. Try this:

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: Note that the `~/.ssh/` directory must also have permissions of `700`: `chmod 700 ~/.ssh`.

Comment: In fact my problem is precisely that I can't change any permissions via Git Bash, when I try, it doesn't launch any errors, but then it didn't work...

Comment: I didn't really solve this issue, but I found out that on an other user account (created in this aim), I can generate and use my ssh key without any problem... So I still don't get what is wrong but I avoided the issue ^^